# This web site needs a different Google Maps API key

Tags: google-maps

I'm getting this popup on a page where we integrated google maps API.  Now the strange thing is with some people in the office it works fine regardless of browser with others there's this popup, saying

> This web site needs a different Google Maps API key....

When I save the page where we installed this locally as html file and open that one it also works on my computer.

When I check the chrome developers tools I see a

> Uncaught ReferenceError: GClientGeocoder is not defined

on my computer whereas some of my colleagues on the same page he doesn't have this error

Comment: Have you tried registering for a new API key and using that?

Comment: @Mano Marks - Yes it makes no difference at all

Comment: Can you link to the page so that we can debug it? BTW, GClientGeocoder is a Maps API V2 object. V2 is deprecated, and could be shut off as early as May so you might want to check your code and upgrade.